# How to create a clean link for each user's page (Mode rewrite)

Tags: apache

Hellо, I have a user's profile page, which can be accessed by

```
root/profile.php?user=batman
```

I want to make a cleaner link, like

```
root/profile/batman
```

I know that it is possible to do with mode rewrite in htaccess, which would read root/profile/batman as root/profile.php?user=batman. The problem is whatever I tried doesn't work. Can someone show me the correct rewrite statement.
Thank you!

Comment: There are tons of tutorials, just put some effort and try to find them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming user name will include only alphabets. This rule will work

```
RewriteRule ^root/profile/([a-z]+) root/profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```